# Speed up YAML file processing in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, spring-bean

I'm trying to read YAML properties file using the [@PropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) annotation in Spring Boot.
**configuration.yaml** file has about **7.5K** lines of data in the below format:

```
# Configuration for privilege management
---
role-configuration:
  roles:
    - name: Agent
      groups:
        -name: privilege-group
group-configuration:
  groups:
    - name: privilege-group
privilege-configuration:
  privileges:
    - name: admin-dashboard-view
      description: View Admin dashboard
      groups:
        - name: privilege-group
    - name: admin-dashboard-edit
      description: Edit Admin dashboard
      groups:
        - name: privilege-group
     ....
     ...
     ..
```

**Configuration bean** and **YAML specific PropertySourceFactory** has been implemented by following this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource)

**PrivilegeProvider.java**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "privilege-configuration")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:security/configuration.yaml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
@Data # lombok annotation for generating getter/setter and other helper functions
public class PrivilegeProvider {
    private List<Privilege> privileges;
}
```

**YamlPropertySourceFactory.java**

```
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {
    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource) throws IOException {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(encodedResource.getResource());

        Properties properties = factory.getObject();

        return new PropertiesPropertySource(encodedResource.getResource().getFilename(), properties);
    }
}
```

All the data is successfully loaded from YAML file but it is **taking *~5-7 minutes* to load, which is quite a lot of time given the file size**.

Can this be optimized? or is there any other way in which I can implement the same?

Comment: Spring uses SnakeYAML to read in the file, have you tried just creating rough code to read it in to see how long that takes? If that goes fast you could try configuring your app through more manual means of defining your own `@Bean` that provides the `List<Privilege>`.

Comment: At last, I end up doing that only without making any changes in YAML format. Now it is only taking couple of seconds.
Coming to the questing why is it slow with **@PropertySource**? I took snap shots using jstack and main thread was waiting on addAll method for the delayed duration @Welsh

Comment: I'm not sure, I imagine the `@PropertySource` is trying to do additional work than just parsing the YAML, it could be because of how the data is structured. You may have better luck with the [Spring Boot Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot) if you can provide a repository that can reproduce the issue.